# Detach isn't working (Two Fragments with FlipView)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, flipview

I'm working with fragments and flipview but I'm having some problems with this.

When my app opens the first screen show my feed with the FlipView. When I choose another tab of my fragments the fragment of the feed didn't hide or detach. I debugged many times and the code arrives in the detached line but didn't work.

Here is my code

MainActivity class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FontManager.getInstance().initialize(this, R.xml.fonts);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFBSession = new FBSessionsManager();
        mActionBar = getActionBar();
        fm = getFragmentManager();
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();

        TabHost.OnTabChangeListener mTabChangeListener = new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK);

                FeedPrincipalList mFeedFragment = (FeedPrincipalList) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAB_TAG_FEED);
                EverythingFragmentList mEverythingFragment = (EverythingFragmentList) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAB_TAG_ALL_EVERYTHING);
                PaymentFragment mPaymentFragment = (PaymentFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAB_TAG_PAYMENT);
                ConsultFragmentList mConsultFragmentList = (ConsultFragmentList) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAB_TAG_M_CONSULT);
                ProfileFragmentList mProfileFragmentList = (ProfileFragmentList) fm.findFragmentByTag(TAB_TAG_M_PROFILE);

                if (mFeedFragment != null){
                    ft.detach(mFeedFragment);
//                    ft.commit();
                }

                if (mEverythingFragment != null)
                    ft.detach(mEverythingFragment);

                if (mPaymentFragment != null)
                    ft.detach(mPaymentFragment);

                if (mConsultFragmentList != null)
                    ft.detach(mConsultFragmentList);

                if (mProfileFragmentList != null){
                    ft.detach(mProfileFragmentList);
//                    ft.commit();
                }

                if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase(TAB_TAG_FEED)) {
                    manageContextualActions(true, false);
                    if (mFeedFragment == null) {
                        mFeedFragment = new FeedPrincipalList();
                        ft.add(R.id.realTabContent, mFeedFragment, TAB_TAG_FEED);
                    } else {
                        mFeedFragment = new FeedPrincipalList();
                        ft.attach(mFeedFragment);
                    }
                }

                if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase(TAB_TAG_ALL_EVERYTHING)) {
                    manageContextualActions(false, true);
                    if (mEverythingFragment == null) {
                        mEverythingFragment = new EverythingFragmentList();
                        ft.replace(R.id.realTabContent, mEverythingFragment, TAB_TAG_ALL_EVERYTHING);
                    } else {
                        ft.attach(mEverythingFragment);
                    }
                }

                if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase(TAB_TAG_PAYMENT)) {
                    manageContextualActions(false, true);
                    if (mPaymentFragment == null) {
                        mPaymentFragment = new PaymentFragment();
                        ft.replace(R.id.realTabContent, mPaymentFragment, TAB_TAG_PAYMENT);
                    } else {
                        ft.attach(mPaymentFragment);
                    }
                }

                if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase(TAB_TAG_M_CONSULT)) {
                    manageContextualActions(false, true);
                    if (mConsultFragmentList == null) {
                        mConsultFragmentList = new ConsultFragmentList();
                        ft.replace(R.id.realTabContent, mConsultFragmentList, TAB_TAG_M_CONSULT);
                    } else {
                        ft.attach(mConsultFragmentList);
                    }
                }

                if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase(TAB_TAG_M_PROFILE)) {
                    manageContextualActions(false, false);
                    if (mProfileFragmentList == null) {
                        mProfileFragmentList = new ProfileFragmentList();
                        ft.replace(R.id.realTabContent, mProfileFragmentList, TAB_TAG_M_PROFILE);
                    } else {
                        mProfileFragmentList = new ProfileFragmentList();
                        ft.attach(mProfileFragmentList);
                    }
                }

                ft.commit();
            }
        };

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(mTabChangeListener);
        createAndConfigureTabs();
    }

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void setupActionBar(int stringTitleID) {
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View customTitle = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_title, null);

        ((TextView) customTitle.findViewById(R.id.customTitleActionbar)).setText(getResources().getString(stringTitleID));

        mActionBar.setCustomView(customTitle);
    }

    private void createAndConfigureTabs() {
        mTabFeed = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAG_FEED);
        mTabFeed.setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_btn_feed));
        mTabFeed.setContent(new TabContentCreator(this));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabFeed);

        mTabAllEverything = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAG_ALL_EVERYTHING);
        mTabAllEverything.setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_btn_all_everything));
        mTabAllEverything.setContent(new TabContentCreator(this));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabAllEverything);

        mTabCameraAndPayment = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAG_PAYMENT);
        mTabCameraAndPayment.setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_camera));
        mTabCameraAndPayment.setContent(new TabContentCreator(this));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabCameraAndPayment);

        mTabConsult = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAG_M_CONSULT);
        mTabConsult.setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_btn_consult));
        mTabConsult.setContent(new TabContentCreator(this));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabConsult);

        mTabMyProfile = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TAG_M_PROFILE);
        mTabMyProfile.setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_btn_profile));
        mTabMyProfile.setContent(new TabContentCreator(this));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabMyProfile);

        mTabWidget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
        for (int i = 0; i minor 5; i++) {
             View v = mTabWidget.getChildAt(i);
            v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.screen_background_light_transparent);

            if (i == 4)
                v.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 12);
        }
    }

private class TabContentCreator implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
        private Context mContext;

        public TabContentCreator(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            View v = new View(mContext);
            return v;
        }
    }
```

FeedFragment class

```
public class FeedPrincipalList extends android.app.Fragment implements FlipView.OnFlipListener, FlipView.OnOverFlipListener, FlipView.OnClickListener {

    private static int timelinePage = 1, mPageCount = 0;
    private FlipView mFlipView;
    private FeedPrincipalAdapter mAdapter;
    private FBSessionsManager fbSessionsManager;
    private List mList;
    private Context context;
    private int posicaoTela;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_flipview, container);

        ((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity()).setupActionBar(R.string.title_fragment_feed);

        mFlipView = (FlipView) view.findViewById(R.id.fv_feedFlipView_FlipView);
        mFlipView.setOnFlipListener(this);
        mFlipView.setOverFlipMode(OverFlipMode.RUBBER_BAND);
        mFlipView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(R.id.empty_view));
        mFlipView.setOnOverFlipListener(this);
        mFlipView.setOnClickListener(this);

        fbSessionsManager = new FBSessionsManager(getActivity());

        if (mList == null)
            new LoadFeedPrincipalData().execute();

        return super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFlippedToPage(FlipView v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("pageflip", "Page: " + position);
        posicaoTela = position;
        if(position > mFlipView.getPageCount()-3 && mFlipView.getPageCount() {

        private UtilWS ws;
        private JSONObject toSend;
        private JsonArray rsArray;
        private JsonParser parser;

        public LoadFeedPrincipalData() {
            ws = new UtilWS();
            toSend = new JSONObject();
            parser = new JsonParser();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                toSend.put("token", fbSessionsManager.getStoredPrivateSession()[0]);
                toSend.put("userId", fbSessionsManager.getStoredPrivateSession()[1]);
                toSend.put("page", timelinePage);

                String[] jsonResult = ws.post(UtilWS.URL_TIMELINE, toSend.toString());
                if (jsonResult[0].equals("200")) {
                    JsonObject temp = parser.parse(jsonResult[1]).getAsJsonObject();
                    Log.i("JSON",": "+temp.toString());
                    if (temp.get("success").getAsBoolean()) {
                        rsArray = temp.get("looks").getAsJsonArray();
                        if (mPageCount == 0)
                            mPageCount = temp.get("pageCount").getAsInt();
                        for (JsonElement el : rsArray) {
                            if (mList == null)
                                mList = new ArrayList();
                            temp = (JsonObject) el;
                            FeedPrincipalTO tempTudo = new FeedPrincipalTO(temp.get("lookId").getAsString(), temp.get("photoUrl1").getAsString(), temp.get("photoUrl2").getAsString(), temp.get("jaVotou").getAsBoolean(),temp.get("photoVoted").getAsInt() ,temp.get("photo1Total").getAsString(), temp.get("photo2Total").getAsString());
                            mList.add(tempTudo);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (mList != null) {
                Log.i("mList","mLista");
                mAdapter = new FeedPrincipalAdapter(context,mList);
                mAdapter.setCallback(new FeedPrincipalAdapter.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageRequested(int page) {
                        mFlipView.smoothFlipTo(page);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void voteUp(int position) {
                        Log.i("TESTE","position = " + posicaoTela);
                        mAdapter.getView(position, null, null).postInvalidate();
//      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
                if (timelinePage == 1) {
                    mFlipView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
//                    initListenerList();
                } else {
                    ((FeedPrincipalAdapter) mFlipView.getAdapter()).updateList(mList);
                    ((FeedPrincipalAdapter) mFlipView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                mFlipView.setAdapter(new FeedPrincipalAdapter(context,null));
            }
        }

//        private void initListenerList() {
//            getListView().setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
//
//                }
//
//                @Override
//                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
//                    if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount != 0) {
//                        if (timelinePage minor mPageCount) {
//                            timelinePage++;
//                            new LoadFeedPrincipalData().execute();
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
//            });
//        }
    }
}
```

Please, help me with this!!!

I'm using the FlipView https://github.com/emilsjolander/android-FlipView

Thanks!!!

Comment: Anyone help me with this, please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem.

First I changed my Main Class a little.

I changed this two ifs (this fragments uses FlipView) in the MainActivity class.

```
if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase(TAB_TAG_FEED)) {
    manageContextualActions(true, false);
    if (mFeedFragment == null) {
        mFeedFragment = new FeedPrincipalList();
        ft.add(R.id.realTabContent, mFeedFragment, TAB_TAG_FEED);
    } else {
        // mFeedFragment = new FeedPrincipalList();
        ft.attach(mFeedFragment);
    }
}

if (tabId.equalsIgnoreCase(TAB_TAG_M_PROFILE)) {
    manageContextualActions(false, false);
    if (mProfileFragmentList == null) {
        mProfileFragmentList = new ProfileFragmentList();
        ft.add(R.id.realTabContent, mProfileFragmentList, TAB_TAG_M_PROFILE);
    } else {
        // mProfileFragmentList = new ProfileFragmentList();
        ft.attach(mProfileFragmentList);
    }
}
```

Second I changed my method onCreateView of my FeedFragment class.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

        ((MainFragmentActivity) getActivity()).setupActionBar(R.string.title_fragment_feed);

        fbSessionsManager = new FBSessionsManager(getActivity());

        if (mList == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_flipview, container,true);
            mFlipView = (FlipView) view.findViewById(R.id.fv_feedFlipView_FlipView);
            mFlipView.setOnFlipListener(this);
            mFlipView.setOverFlipMode(OverFlipMode.RUBBER_BAND);
            mFlipView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(R.id.empty_view));
            mFlipView.setOnOverFlipListener(this);
            new LoadFeedPrincipalData().execute();
        }

        return super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    }
```

You can see the difference. I only inflate the view in the first time. After this my mList(it's a List of MyGetSetClass) it's not null anymore.

And to finish I Override this two methods on my FeedFragment class.

```
@Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
//        Log.i("onDetach", "FeedPrincipalList");
        mList = null;
        timelinePage = 1;
        mPageCount = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
//        Log.i("onStart", "FeedPrincipalList");
        this.mFlipView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
//        Log.i("onStop","FeedPrincipalList");
        this.mFlipView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

In the detach method I clean all my static variables that I will use when I start the app again.

The onStart and the onStop I use to change the Visibility of my FlipView.

That's it.

I hope this help everyone!!!